# $http.get(api) is called again after successful http call to api2

Tags: php, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS (few tutorials in 1.6 completed) and wanted to understand API call using $http variable in Controller.
I have API which gives JSON information about all users (say /api/users) and another API which gives details of given user for given id (say /api/user/id).
Now I am trying to make a link for each user in /users page to point to /user/id page using function call getUserDetails.

**Problem:** I am not able to see user data in /user/id page, but /users loads fine

**Questions:** If I use the chrome debugger, I see /users http call works fine. In fact clicking on any user link also hits debugger statement at line 11, but it later, it also hits debugger at 5.

1. Why is this going into line 5 debugger (mostly because of which my "user" variable is not obtained in the html page)?
2. Is there any workaround for this? Would declaring user variable at line 3 be helpful? (not tried this as personally I feel this is not the right way?)
3. Slightly on design side of API- Let's say I have description of all users in /api/users call itself. In that case how can I modify the controller (and html) so as to pass specific user information to new page? Is this approach recommended?

**Constraints:** I am unable to load it without $scope variable so any suggestion with $scope involved would help. "raw" tag is also required for now to ignore PHP parsing.

Tried searching existing questions but could not find much information. In case it was due to lack of good keywords, do point me to any helpful existing answers. :)

Below is userlist.htm (shows list of all users)

```
{% raw %}
<div ng-controller="UserController">
    <div ng-repeat="user in users">
        <h3><a href="/user/{{ user.id }}" ng-click="getUserDetails(user.id)">{{ user.name }}</a></h3>
        <!-- userdetails.htm is called with this -->
    </div>
</div>
{% endraw %}
{% put scripts %}
    <script src="{{ 'assets/javascript/UserController.js'|theme}}"></script>
{% endput %}
```

userdetails.htm (shows details of any selected user)

```
{% raw %}
<div ng-controller="UserController">
    <h3>{{ user.name }}</h3>
    <!-- Some more user information here-->
</div>
{% endraw %}

{% put scripts %}
    <script src="{{ 'assets/javascript/UserController.js'|theme}}"></script>
{% endput %}
```

AngularJS Controller defined here:

```
app.controller("UserController", ['$scope', '$http', '$log', function ($scope, $http, $log) {
    var userCtrlScope = $scope;

    $http.get('/api/users').then(function(data){
        debugger;
        userCtrlScope.users = data;
    });

    userCtrlScope.getUserDetails = function(id){
        $http.get('/api/user/' + id).then(function(data) {
            debugger;
            userCtrlScope.user = data;
        });
    };
}]);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need `href="/user/{{ user.id }}"`, it will go to `user/5` route. If it is a goal to go to this route, you should have separated controller for that route and inside it, call `$http.get('/api/user/' + id)` where `id` you can get, for example, from `$routeParams` (`$routeParams.id`) if you use angularjs router or `$stateParams` (`$stateParams.id`) if you use UI router. How you load `userdetails.htm`?

Comment: Currently laravel loads userdetails.htm for me. As per your suggestion, let me try using UI Router/Angular JS Router. Thanks a lot for quick response and suggestion. :)